# Performance and correctness of selecting only most recent entries across joined tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `things` and `purchases`. I am trying to select only the most recent purchase record for each thing.

```
CREATE TABLE `things` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `product_image` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `unique_barcode` (`barcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=643 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thing_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('IMMEDIATELY','SOON','LATER','INACTIVE') DEFAULT 'IMMEDIATELY',
  `estimated_number_of_days` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '7',
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `purchase_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `predicted_replace_days` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '7',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `foreign_key_things` (`thing_id`),
  KEY `foreign_key_users` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `foreign_key_things` FOREIGN KEY (`thing_id`) REFERENCES `things` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `foreign_key_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The following query (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/756001/11577)) *appears* to work. My questions are:

1. Is this actually doing what I want it to?
2. How can I optimize the performance of this query (indexes, etc.)?
3. Is there a more efficient way to do this in MySQL?

SQL:

```
SELECT purchases.id AS purchase_id, thing_id, purchase_date, name, predicted_replace_days, product_image, barcode
FROM (
    SELECT id, MAX(purchase_date)
    FROM purchases
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY purchase_date DESC
) AS sub
JOIN purchases ON purchases.id = sub.id
INNER JOIN things on thing_id = things.id
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY thing_id;
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I think I was overcomplicating it. Here is what looks like a simpler and more correct query:

```
SELECT purchases.id AS purchase_id, MAX(purchase_date) AS purchase_date, predicted_replace_days, name
FROM purchases
INNER JOIN things ON purchases.thing_id = things.id
GROUP BY thing_id
```

Comment: I doubt this is working for you.  You're getting the date of each ID of the purchase, not the thing ID.  So you could use that to get the last purchased things but then you can't get back to the actual purchase row.  So you'd need to join back on the date and thingID.  Then deal with dupes...

Comment: There seem to be more things than purchases -- which way is the "many:1" relationship??

Comment: @LoztInSpace: Yeah, it's definitely not giving me the right data.

Comment: @RickJames: The autoincrement values are messed up because of an application error (since fixed). There are many purchases for each thing.

Comment: Woah!  Dodgy MySQL aggregates to the rescue.  I can't tell you if it's going to work in MySQL but it won't even execute on any other DB engine.  Take expert advice on that before committing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT purchases.id AS purchase_id, thing_id, purchase_date, name, predicted_replace_days, product_image, barcode
FROM (
    SELECT thing_id, MAX(purchase_date) pd
    FROM purchases
    GROUP BY thing_id   
) AS sub
JOIN purchases ON purchases.id = sub.thing_id and sub.pd=purchase_date
INNER JOIN things on thing_id = things.id
WHERE user_id = 1
```